# turbolinks:load eventlistener in rails 7 partial not executing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, partials

I have a partial with some radio buttons and a submit button.

```
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
              <form>
        <% @options.each_with_index do |option, index| %>
          <div class="mb-3 text-center custom-radio">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios<%= index + 1 %>" value="<%= index %>">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios<%= index + 1 %>"><%= option %></label>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class = "container text-center" style = "padding-top:20px">
    <button id="submit-answer-button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled> Submit </button>
  </div>
```

I also have this script underneath the same partial file:

```
<script>
console.log('test')
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
console.log('test1')
  let submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-answer-button');
  let radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

  for (let i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
    radioButtons[i].addEventListener('change', function() {

      if (this.checked) {

        submitButton.disabled = false;
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

I confirmed that the console produces 'test' but not 'test1' so something is wrong with turbolinks. I've tried a lot of different things like using DomContentLoad instead and placing this in the application view. Nothing works! The turbolinks:load simply refuses to execute.

Comment: As a really hacky workaround, I've replaced the turbolinks:load with mouseup which now works but creates unnecessary eventlisteners each time someone clicks.